# Adding banner to a completed game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, banner

I made a game(which already fills up the screen) but now I want to add a banner to it using admob.

If I add a banner now, part of the screen I am using will be blocked because of the banner. How do I insert the banner without overlaying my game scene?

PS: All sizes are based on my frame.size, So I tried

```
frame.size.height = 0.9 * frame.size.height
```

But this doesn't work(gives error)

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: why are you using 0.9 to calculate height of banner frame.

Comment: SO I can add a banner under it

Comment: where do you want to show banner on the top of the screen or bottom ?

Comment: I want to show it at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify directly a view.frame or .bounds (and it's deprecated to do that).

To do that you'll have to create a pretty new frame :

```
gameView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(gameView.bounds),
                            CGRectGetMinY(gameView.bounds),
                            CGRectGetWidth(gameView.bounds),
                            CGRectGetHeight(gameView.bounds) * 0.9f);
```

Comment: Do I do this before calling my GameScene?

Comment: After your game scene is displayed. If you do before, the gameView.bounds would be 0

Comment: but what is the "gameView", do you mean GameScene?

Comment: Yeah it's a name I took for explicit example. It's your gamescene/view/i don't know the name ;)

Comment: I Dont understand what you mean, do you mean the name of the swift file?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
if (contentFrame.size.width < contentFrame.size.height) {
      _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
} else {
      _bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
}    
CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;    
if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {   
      contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
      bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
} else {
      bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
}            
[UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
      _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
      [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
      _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}];
```

Here content view is instance of UIViewController and _bannerView is GADBannerView instance.